# TypeError: Is not a constructor, exporting a class object from another file

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have searching for a solution for this error and nothing works so far. I want to export a class from another file so that it can still be used by the main file.

This is the error I get when I run the program.

> ```
> E:\VSC\block.js:5
> let block1 = new Blockchain();
>                  ^ 
> TypeError: Blockchain is not a constructor
> ```

[image]

Here is my code.

```js
const Blockchain = require('./blockchain.js');

const Transaction = require('./blockchain.js');

let block1 = new Blockchain();
```

I suspect this is some sort of syntax error but I cant see anything wrong with the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the blockchain.js code?

Comment: Also, why are you _require-ing_ `blockchain.js` twice?

Comment: If you do not mind, could you please share Blockchain.js?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the source code for `blockchain.js` so we don't know how things are exported from there. My guess is both `Blockchain` and `Transaction` are exported and I'm assuming none of them are default export. If this is the case, you can try this:

```js
const { Blockchain, Transaction } = require('./blockchain.js');

let block1 = new Blockchain();
```

Answer (score -1):

It could simply be that the module.exports was not placed outside the closing bracket in your